# Not able to create accounts for Private Ethereum Blockchain using Geth and Web3 API

Tags: ethereum

I am unable to create accounts for Private Ethereum Blockchain using Geth and Web3 API. 
personal.newAccount(passwd) is not working for me. Please explain how to create account using above command.
And also, I am unable to install "ethereumjs-accounts".

Comment: Please provide more details of what you tried, and what went wrong. This question will probably get deleted and won't get answered if you don't improve it.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to search the internet why the "geth json rpc personal api" is not working, you will [find an excellent answer on Ethereum Stack Exchange](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1413/87) which I'd like to quote in full:

> ### First, a note on safety:
>
> **You should not make the `personal` API available over RPC**
>
> If you are on a local, trusted machine, you should use IPC instead of RPC. Otherwise, anyone who can connect to your node via RPC can try to brute-force your passwords and steal your Ether.
>
> All administrative APIs are available by default over IPC, so no need to use any flags with geth
>
> #### To connect via IPC:
>
> Install my library:
> `npm install web3_extended`
>
> ```
> var web3_extended = require('web3_extended');
>
> var options = {
>   host: '/home/user/.ethereum/geth.ipc',
>   ipc:true,
>   personal: true, 
>   admin: false,
>   debug: false
> };
>
> var web3 = web3_extended.create(options);
>
> web3.personal.newAccount("password",function(error,result){
>     if(!error){
>         console.log(result);
>     }
> });
> ```
>
> Replace the `host` variable with the proper path for your system.
>
> Note: All requests via IPC must be asynchronous.
>
> ---
>
> #### Some Alternatives:
>
> I don't know why you want to create new accounts via web3, but it's likely not the best way to do what you're trying to achieve. It is much safer and more modular to use a [hooked web3 provider](https://github.com/ConsenSys/hooked-web3-provider) with a client-side [light wallet](https://github.com/ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet) or to simply use the [Mist browser](https://github.com/ethereum/mist) which handles all accounts for you.
>
> #### Now for the technique (don't do this)
>
> You need to enable the `personal` API over RPC. Do this by starting geth with
>
> `geth --rpc --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3,personal"`
>
> Then you can use the `personal_newAccount` method via RPC. It's not implemented in web3.js, so you need to manually issue the RPC request. For example with curl:
>
> `curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"personal_newAccount","params":["password"],"id":1}' localhost:8545`
>
> creates a new account with password `password` and returns the address:
>
> `{"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":"0x05ca0ddf7e7506672f745b2b567f1d33b7b55f4f"}`
> There is some [basic documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Go-ethereum-management-API%27s#personal_unlockAccount)
>
> **Alternatively:**
> Use the unofficial [extended web3.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3_extended)
>
> - this allows you to use the `personal`, `admin` and `miner` APIs via a standard web3.js interface.

*Published on [Feb 16 at 8:34](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/1414/87) and released under terms of [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) by [Tjaden Hess](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/131/tjaden-hess).*

Answer (score 1):

The command must be `personal.newAccount()`

Then the console asks for passphrase, give your required password then it again asks for confirmation.

An output in the form of Address("0x----------------------------") will appear.It is 1 account/address for your private network.